# Devise and OmniAuth. Vkontakte scope problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, omniauth, vk

I just got setup using Rails 3, Devise and OmniAuth via https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview.

I want integrate my app with vkontakte.ru. When i'm using this config everything goes fine i can create user and i can access user data.

```
config.omniauth :vkontakte, 'xxx', 'xxx'
```

But when i'm adding a scope param

```
config.omniauth :vkontakte, 'xxx', 'xxx', { 
   :scope => "notify,friends,photos,notes,docs,pages,wall,offline"
}
```

omniauth raise failure(redirects me on user sign up page and dont store data in env["omniauth.auth"]).
I'll be appreciated for any help.

Comment: For suffering people, do not read that article : 
[link](http://vkontakte.ru/developers.php?o=-1&p=%CF%F0%E0%E2%E0%20%E4%EE%F1%F2%F3%EF%E0%20%EF%F0%E8%EB%EE%E6%E5%ED%E8%E9)

Read this one: 
[link](http://vkontakte.ru/developers.php?o=-1&p=%CF%F0%E0%E2%E0%20%EF%F0%E8%EB%EE%E6%E5%ED%E8%E9)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like that's because of the attribute expires_in=0 in the VK oauth response, that indicates the long-living token that was requested by the 'offline' scope and leads to the instant token refreshing by omniauth.
I've just submitted patch [here](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/pull/410).